# Get difference of values between two dates

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this documents

```
{
    "url" : "/url1.php",
    "date" : ISODate("2016-01-02T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "hits" : 104
},
{
    "url" : "/url2.php",
    "date" : ISODate("2016-01-02T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "hits" : 121
},
{
    "url" : "/url3.php",
    "date" : ISODate("2016-01-02T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "hits" : 75
},
{
    "url" : "/url1.php",
    "date" : ISODate("2016-05-11T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "hits" : 100
},
{
    "url" : "/url2.php",
    "date" : ISODate("2016-05-11T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "hits" : 104
}
```

And I want to get difference between two dates, sort by this difference. If some document not exist in second date then the difference is first value.

```
{
    "url" : "/url1.php",
    "diff": 4
},
{
    "url" : "/url2.php",
    "diff": 17
},
{
    "url" : "/url3.php",
    "diff": 75
}
```

The url3.php not exists in second date.

I have tried this

```
db.collection.aggregate(
{
   $match : 
      {
       $or:[{"date":{$gte:ISODate("2016-01-02"),$lte:ISODate("2016-01-02")}},{"date":{$gte:ISODate("2016-05-11"),$lte:ISODate("2016-05-11")}}],
       }
   },
   {$group:{_id:{"url":"$url",month:{$month:"$date"}},total:{"$sum":"$visitas"}}},
   {$group:{_id:{"url":"$_id.url",super:{"$subtract":[{$max:"$total"},{$min:"$total"}]}},max:{$first:"$total"},min:{$last:"$total"}}},
    {$group:{_id:{"url":"$_id.url",difference:{"$subtract":["$max","$min"]},"dateHight":"$max","dateLow":"$min","diff2":"$super"}}},
    {$unwind:"$_id.difference"},
    {$match:{"_id.difference":{$ne:0}}},
   {$sort:{"_id.difference":-1}}
)
```

This show

```
{
    "url" : "/url1.php",
    "diff": 4
},
{
    "url" : "/url2.php",
    "diff": 17
}
```

But not url3.php because not exists in second date

Comment: english is perfect, don't worry :) what have you tried so far? any code to show? any error messages?

Comment: Thanks Matias, Done!

Comment: But I can see only one `date` field!

Comment: Yes, is the same collection. Only there are one field of date. Now I group by month (this example), week or day. 

The problem is that in second range of date not exists this url.

Comment: What is your MongoDB version?

Comment: Hi, MongoDB version is 3.2

Answer (score 3):

You need to first [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort) your document by "date" in ascending order. From there, you then [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group) them by "url". The preliminary sorting stage allow us to use the [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first) operator and his partner in crime [`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last) to return the first and last "hits".

But this is not enough we also need to return the number of document per group. This is because we need to perform a logical [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)ition processing in the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract). Here the condition is `$eq` which return true when we  only have one document in the group and false otherwise. We then set the first hit to `0` as the returned value of  expression.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
   [
        { "$sort": { "date": -1 } }, 
        { "$group": { 
            "_id": "$url", 
            "lastHit": { "$last": "$hits" }, 
            "firstHit": { "$first": "$hits" }, 
            "count": { "$sum": 1 } 
        }}, 
        { "$project": { 
            "diff": { 
                "$subtract": [ 
                    "$lastHit", 
                    { "$cond": [ 
                        { "$eq": [ "$count", 1 ] }, 
                        0, 
                        "$firstHit" 
                    ]} 
                ] 
            } 
        }} 
    ]
)
```

The query yields the following result.

```
{ "_id" : "/url2.php", "diff" : 17 }
{ "_id" : "/url3.php", "diff" : 75 }
{ "_id" : "/url1.php", "diff" : 4 }
```